# Rails 4 cant mass assign attr_accessor method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mass-assignment

I have the following model:

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :properties
   serialize :properties
end
```

When I call:

```
thing = Something.new({name:"foo",properties:{key_1:"val"}})
```

thing has name populated but not properties. I can manually assign properties as such:

```
thing.properties = {key_1:"val"}
```

and that works fine, but I cannot make it work through mass assignment.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Check the log file; there is likely to be a message `unpermitted parameters: properties`.

Comment: Did you try `Something.new({name:"foo",properties_attributes:{key_1:"val"}})` ?

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 uses [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) in the controller. So while having your attrs set in the model, you still have to `permit` params in the controller.

This is the line to look for/add into your controller:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:thing).permit(:parm1, :param2)
end
```

Comment: He is not using `params`, so it won't help.